# Do Unique Instance Session ID's Live Inside Of Programs?

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier

I am looking for a variable that I can just call from C#, like Environment.Username that is unique to the instance of a particular application (like a timestamp for when the application was initially opened or something).

If this is available, that would make my project a lot easier.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id
```

is unique for each instance of an application process. It does change every time the application is restarted though :)

Comment: Is this a constant value during the life time of the application instance?  Does it need to be defined or set manually?

Comment: You don't set it. It is generated by the kernel when your process starts. It is unique and does not change for the lifetime of a process. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180(v=VS.85).aspx for more information on process IDs (this is the underlying function that the .Id property calls in the .net framework)

Comment: Sounds good, this will make my development work easier, and my program more reliable. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this id only 4 digits long?  I can see that if a process is instantiated very frequently (like millions of times per second) the possibility of having duplicate process id's is much greater (which could cause problems).  How is this number determined, and how can it be ensured that it is unique?

Comment: At no point can there be duplicate process IDs active at the same time. The kernel ensure that it is unique when it assigns them. They're not all four digits, you will note that the system processes tend to have smaller numbers, and user processes tend to have larger ones. It most likely (although this is an internal implementation detail and not known) uses a free list of process IDs to reuse ones that are no longer active.

Comment: Washu, thank you for that additional explanation, my fears have been put to rest :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Guid.NewGuid()`, which is unique. If you need it for the lifetime of your application, you could use

```
public static Guid ApplicationId = Guid.NewGuid();
```

which would get populated the first time this type is used.

Comment: Something that doesn't require any setting and just lives inside of C#.  I'll add an addendum to my OP.

Answer (score 0):

Every process under Windows has a unique Process ID. You can access it via the [`Process.Id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.id.aspx) property. To obtain an instance of `Process` corresponding to the currently running instance of your program call [`Process.GetCurrentProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.getcurrentprocess.aspx). Every instance of your program will be represented as a separate process in Windows, and hence will receive a different (and unique) Process ID.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you right. Don't you need this?

```
public static class MyClass {
    // fore every process this value will be unique, but same for whole "life" of process
    private static readonly Guid unique = Guid.NewGuid();
    public static Guid Unique { get { return unique; } }
}
```